# How do I keep group by values for each row in a pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame where I run group_by. It truncates and does not fill down the row value if the row value is the same. I want to fill in this value and keep it for a table.

```
data = data.groupby(['Item', 'Year', 'Quarter']).sum().sort_values(['Item', 'Year','Quarter'])
```

gives

```
Orange     2022 4         4173889.0
                1         1144577.0
Apple      2021 1          270160.0
```

whereas I want

```
Orange     2022 4         4173889.0
Orange     2022 1         1144577.0
Apple      2021 1          270160.0
```

How do I accomplish this? I am looking at `pivot` and `pivot_table` now

Comment: Try `.reset_index()` at the end.